# How to fix border top right radius where image is on top

Tags: html, css, border

I have got this layout where the image sits on top and has the top right radius of 20px. border-bottom-left-radius is working though.

Here's the mockup.

[image]

This is what I've got so far.

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
margin: 10px;
}
.featured-block {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 31px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

.featured-block .featured-image img {
  width:100%;
    object-fit: cover;

}
.featured-block .featured-block-content {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="featured-block">
            <div class="featured-image">
               <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/455x385" alt="" title="">
            </div>
            <div class="featured-block-content">
              <h2>Dolore am inusa </h2>
              <p>Viderae cullibus ari bercimus magnissi venim vereste mquatur aut audisquo vendel iur molupta tiaecto omnihictur, sa sinum voluptiis.</p>
              <a href="" class="underlined">Read more</a>
            </div>
          </div>

</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Got this working. had to add 'overflow:hidden". Thanks.

Comment: Please add 'overflow:hidden' in '.featured-block' class selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an `overflow: hidden`. Your `border-top-right-radius: 20px;` is working but the image is overflowing the `featured-block`.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 10px;
}

.featured-block {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 31px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

.featured-block .featured-image img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.featured-block .featured-block-content {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="featured-block">
    <div class="featured-image">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/455x385" alt="" title="">
    </div>
    <div class="featured-block-content">
      <h2>Dolore am inusa </h2>
      <p>Viderae cullibus ari bercimus magnissi venim vereste mquatur aut audisquo vendel iur molupta tiaecto omnihictur, sa sinum voluptiis.</p>
      <a href="" class="underlined">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Another option is to also add `border-top-right-radius: 20px;` to the image itself.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 10px;
}

.featured-block {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 31px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

.featured-block .featured-image img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

.featured-block .featured-block-content {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="featured-block">
    <div class="featured-image">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/455x385" alt="" title="">
    </div>
    <div class="featured-block-content">
      <h2>Dolore am inusa </h2>
      <p>Viderae cullibus ari bercimus magnissi venim vereste mquatur aut audisquo vendel iur molupta tiaecto omnihictur, sa sinum voluptiis.</p>
      <a href="" class="underlined">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```